# TRPC optimistic updates on nested arrays

Tags: react-query, trpc

I'm developing a todo app using TRPC+Prisma+NextJS

Right now, the app shows a list of todos stored in database.

I'd like to optimistically update the state of the todo (finish / pending)

Right now, I can apply the optimistic update creating a new object from the original one with this code:

```js
const newmap = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevData));

newmap.map((el) => {
    if(el.id === el.completed = completed;
}
  return el
})

ctx.todos.getAll.setData(undefined, newmap )
```

The question is if a can make it more simple.

[Reading React Query documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/optimistic-updates#updating-a-single-todo) I think it should be possible filtering the todos cached by id:

```js
useMutation({
  mutationFn: updateTodo,
  // When mutate is called:
  onMutate: async (newTodo) => {
    // Cancel any outgoing refetches
    // (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
    await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['todos', newTodo.id] })

    // Snapshot the previous value
    const previousTodo = queryClient.getQueryData(['todos', newTodo.id])

    // Optimistically update to the new value
    queryClient.setQueryData(['todos', newTodo.id], newTodo)

    // Return a context with the previous and new todo
    return { previousTodo, newTodo }
  },
```

I tried to replicate this using TRPC helpers methods (getData) but I cannot filter the list of todos

Is it possible to change one todo from the list of stored todos in cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using tRPC's `useContext`. In tRPC, most of the operations you would do using the Query Client in React Query can be done using `useContext`, which is effectively a typesafe wrapper around it. My example code just toggles the `completed` field given an ID, but it should give you an idea of how to implement your optimistic update.

```js
const utils = api.useContext();
const todos = api.useless.todos.useQuery();
const complete = api.useless.complete.useMutation({
  onMutate: async ({ id }) => {
    await utils.useless.todos.cancel();
    utils.useless.todos.setData(undefined, (old) => {
      return old?.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed,
          };
        }
        return todo;
      });
    });
  },
  onSettled: () => todos.refetch(),
});
```